# Calling any function from dll throws error

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dll

I'm making game engine in c++ which is compiled into dll. For last 2 weeks i was doing very boring cleaning of code to make it easier to use, unfortunantely didnt make any backup. Now when i put call to any function from that dll  inside executable code it shows error window, when executable starts, which tells error code 0xc0000142. Compiler doesnt show any warning that could lead to this, no linking error, nothing. I have no clue what could do this. I'm using linker to link dll instead of loading it dynamically. Does anybody know what can trigger this error?

Comment: *{DLL Initialization Failed}*

Comment: Rebuild the library and try again.

Comment: `when i call any function from that dll it shows error window` Do you have the DLL set to delay-load, by any chance? Otherwise the error would be more likely to occur at startup rather than first-call time.

Comment: Maybe the wrong value is being returned from DLLMain().

Comment: @dvix i forgot to mention that, the error occurs right on app startup when i add any function from that dll to that app, it makes error right on start because if i put cout first it won't print, just crash

Comment: @bittickler i don't use dllmain so this is not the problem

Comment: @os2 i've rebuilt it many times, tried to restart pc just to make sure but nothing changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if not delay-load, when you load the process, the dll will also be brought to memory. so this error happens.
How to tackle?
I suggest you to make a fresh plain executable with just basic code and insert this dll. try it.
if successful, insert a function call on a non-functional code (should not be called on startup) and try it.
if the above succeeds, try to add the function call on functional code and try it.
if works means simple DLL is clean.
Then what happens to your original exe, there is a good chance that the a bad copy of DLL is placed in PATH. it is causing the error.

if anything fails in between, you can figure out the issue from DLL. in that case, I suggest you to comment out all code with a fresh blank function. DllMain way next.

sorry for the 'open ended' answer. but for debugging I think you need some pointers to think. you are the one ultimately going to find the result. please post the findings.

Comment: So i made plain executable ran the code it threw runtime error and visual studio pointed me into one function inside my dll, i commented that function out of it, compiled dll and now the app runs without error, now i'm gonna take a look at what's the problem with that code. I hope i can fix it now, thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, i found the problem. When dll is started it called constructor of object. I didn't know why it could be called when nobody calls it. But then i found out that i had static pointer which gets allocated just in "plain file" which lead to the error, it happened probably because functions weren't loaded or something? I don't know, but removing that static pointer creation fixed everything.

Comment: Good that you shared the finding. It may happen to anyone who reads this. For debugging, people need pointers.

Comment: I've looked at the code again and that pointer initialization wasn't actually the problem, problem was that the constructor was working with nullptr, because the constructor was called in "plain file" so it got called before anything else and because my engine wasn't initialized, it didn't load needed pointers and this happened

Comment: Nice catch. Another reason why one should avoid global variables. I recommend you  review your DLL function API. If there is state between calls on that API, consider having the user code maintain it and to pass it as an argument into the calls. This way you can avoid global variables in the dll and it also gets you value for things like concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

Good. Usage of exception is good in scenarios like construction. It does not add much performance overhead when things go well. But neat when nasty things happen. especially good when you give the code to others to maintain.